# Haskell: Find object in list by property

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Is there a way of finding a given "object" by one of it's property?
I tried pattern matching like i would have done in logic programming but I can't figure it out:

```
data Object = Object {
    _prop1 :: type,
    _prop2 :: color,
    _prop3 :: pos
} deriving Eq

type Square = Maybe Object
type Board = [[Square]]

objectlist::Board
objectlist = [[ Just (Object type color pos), Just (Object type color pos)]
...
[ Just (Object type color pos), Just (Object type color pos)]

index_of :: (Int, Int)->Int
index_of (x,y) = fromJust $ elemIndex piece objectlist
    where
        piece = Piece _ _ (x,y)
```

Also, I think my approach to find the index is not good. I used it with a simple list but can't find how to do it with a 2 dim list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated as a comment in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295984/3485629) you are looking for the index in a 2D list. Therefore I think the type of `index_of` should be `(Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)`.

The function [`findIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndex) was suggested in the other answer  to help you make `index_of`. What you need is a generic 2D version of it. Here is how you could implement `findIndex2D`:

```
import           Data.List
import           Data.Maybe

findIndex2D :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findIndex2D pred xs = do
  let maybeIndices = map (findIndex pred) xs
  y <- findIndex isJust maybeIndices
  x <- maybeIndices !! y
  return (x, y)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! It will take a long time to get ride of 5 years of imperative programming habits ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`findIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#findIndex) to get something of that effect.

```
index_of :: (Int, Int)->Int
index_of (x,y) = fromJust $ findIndex piece objectlist
  where
    piece (Piece _ _ pos) = pos == (x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this a good start! Correct me if I'm wrong, but i think this is not working for a two dim list. I got this error:
`• Couldn't match type ‘[Square]’ with ‘Piece’
      Expected type: [Piece]
        Actual type: Board
    • In the second argument of ‘findIndex’, namely ‘initialBoard’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘findIndex piece initialBoard’
      In the expression: fromJust $ findIndex piece initialBoard
`